# First time R user...cant get data into R

Tags: r

I'm a first time R user and I'm trying to run some data. The data consists of two columns. I copied it from the class website and pasted it on notepad. 
I saved the data on my desktop as : act.txt 
Now I'm trying to upload it into R in the same method our professor tought us :

```
data1<- read.table(file="act.txt",header=TRUE)
```

but it's giving me this error :

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file 'act.txt': No such file or directory

Can you please point me in the right direction? 
Thank you!

Comment: You need to provide the full path, *or* (better) make sure your working directory is set correctly.  `?file.choose`, `?dir.choose` (on some operating systems), `?getwd`, `?setwd`, `?list.files` could all be helpful. Depending on operating system/interface you may be able to set working directory from a menu as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you are a first time user I'd suggest you use a IDE. Will greatly help you, and make your life easier. Propably the best arround for new users is RStudio http://www.rstudio.org/

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel installed, you may want to copy from the website into Excel and then save that as CSV.

Then just set your working directory (folder where you're keeping your data) with setwd(), and type read.csv(...).

Alternatively, if you specify the full path like this "C:...\act.txt", make sure to change all "\" to "/".

Comment: I think the potential for introducing strange behavior with Excel conventions for coding are too great to allow me to upvote this advice. I won't downvote because of the other useful material.

Comment: Excel will not help when the problem is just about the file path

Comment: Please do not mention Excel in a data manipulation workflow. We don't want people to get the wrong ideas...

Answer (score 1):

> data1<- read.table(file="act.txt",header=TRUE)

Maybe this is a little too obvious but are you giving the full path of the file? If you are using Windows 7 and it is on your desktop the full path should be something like this:

C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\act.txt

And because this is R, you need forward slashes in the path, not backslashes (which caught me out when I started using R). So perhaps you should try:

data1<- read.table(file="C:/Users/Dan/Desktop/act.txt",header=TRUE)

...but replacing 'Dan' in the above path with your username.